# Magento 2 - Get tax sum

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax, checkout-summary

In checkout It shows a summary with all costs, it also shows the tax costs (**Steuer** [german]).

[image: Tax]

How can I get the tax costs from PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the quote:

```
$totals = $quote->getTotals();
$tax = (isset($totals['tax'])) ? $totals['tax']->getValue(): 0;
```

If you do not have the quote you can inject \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession to your constructor and get the quote using:

```
$quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
```